# How can I make a list of tuples in scala in a function?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, tuples, scala-collections

I am trying to make a list filled with tuples, in a recursive function, so the list can get bigger while iterating. I just don't know how to achieve this in scala.

```
def tryToClaimPosition(player: Int, horizontal: Int , vertical: Int , list: List[(Int, Int)]): Unit = {
if (vertical == gridsize - 1) {
  println(list);
}
if (horizontal < gridsize - 1) {
  if (gameBoard(horizontal)(vertical) == player) {
    val tuple = (horizontal,vertical)
    val list2 = list :: tuple
    tryToClaimPosition(player, horizontal + 1, vertical, list2)
  else {
    tryToClaimPosition(player, horizontal + 1, vertical, list)
  }
}
```

As you see in the snippet above I have a List of tuples and I have a tuple, but I cannot add it.

Comment: What should happen, when `horizontal > gridsize - 1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use immutable list instead, that would be an accumulator. This would be in a more functional way. The function would have no side effect and would return a resulting `List`:

```
def tryToClaimPosition(player: Int, horizontal: Int , vertical: Int , list: List[(Int, Int)]): List[(Int, Int)] = {
  if (vertical == gridsize - 1) {
    list.reverse
  }
  if (horizontal < gridsize - 1) {
    if (gameBoard(horizontal)(vertical) == player) {
      val tuple = (horizontal, vertical)
      tryToClaimPosition(player,horizontal + 1, vertical, tuple::list)
    else {
      tryToClaimPosition(player,horizontal + 1, vertical, list)
    }
  } else Nil
}
```

Notice, that I have prepended the tuple to the List, because it takes constant time (appending is proportional to the size of the `List`). That's why I'm returning `list.reverse`, so that the original ordering is maintained.

Also I asked about the case when `horizontal > gridsize - 1`. Your program does nothing, so I assume, nothing should be returned, hence `Nil` in `else` clause. It is needed, so that there is always a value returned from the function.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many glaring logic and syntax errors. Most pertinent to your question is that fact that `list :: tuple` won't compile because the **right** side of the `::` method must be a `List`.

Use `::` to prepend, not append, to a `List`.